# scala DataFrame access to WrappedArray element in Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new for scala and I am struggling for hours to iterate this WrappedArray in array and print each element

```
  scala> collected
    res73: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = 
    Array([31511,WrappedArray([328,0.7845393], [1264,0.7568395], 
          [933,0.7005877], [78,0.67518044], [787,0.5766443], [806,0.5260384],
          [2505,0.48659027], [1625,0.48547864], [2443,0.47885978], [975,0.4683425],
          [888,0.42476034], [723,0.40946054], [1616,0.39374632], [2466,0.37899566],
          [950,0.37615034], [1336,0.36006662], [812,0.3509268], [1558,0.33291495], 
          [286,0.32301086], [758,0.3210116], [1397,0.3134273], [824,0.29997423], 
          [1698,0.29471087], [689,0.2890404], [10,0.27876395], [1146,0.27792412], 
          [1088,0.27623963], [1352,0.2704942], [710,0.26956537], [2065,0.2597088])])
```

Can anyone let me know how to grep the element from **WrappedArray** in Array ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Miguel I want to make them into two columns like DataFrame

Comment: @RameshMaharjan it helped. btw, do you know what those square brackets mean in WrappedArray ?

Comment: those are structs in dataframe or dataset

Comment: people are just getting crazy to downvote answers even without testing them. I thought it was you @Daniel but it turned out to be someone else

Comment: @RameshMaharjan nah.. I have only 73 point and it's not enough to downvote but I upvoted it.  I wanted to understand data structures in scala. I thought I could access to array just like other languages like java / js but it seems very different

Comment: its different because `collected` is transformed from dataframe or dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of the followings (commented for clarity and for explanations)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
//get the first elements of the WrappedArray in  Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([31511,WrappedArray([328,0.7845393], [1264,0.7568395]...
collected.map(row => row.getAs[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Row]](1).map(struct => struct(0)))

//get the second elements of the WrappedArray in  Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([31511,WrappedArray([328,0.7845393], [1264,0.7568395]...
collected.map(row => row.getAs[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Row]](1).map(struct => struct(1)))

//get the both elements of the WrappedArray in  Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([31511,WrappedArray([328,0.7845393], [1264,0.7568395]...
collected.map(row => row.getAs[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Row]](1).map(struct => (struct(0), struct(1))))

//if you know the struct names and datatypes then 
//get the first element of the WrappedArray in  Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([31511,WrappedArray([328,0.7845393], [1264,0.7568395]...
collected.map(row => row.getAs[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Row]](1).map(struct => (struct.getAs[Int]("_1"), struct.getAs[Double](1))))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you get `Array` of `Row` `Array[Row]` after collecting

As per your data your row contains two data first one as `Int` `31511` and second as `WrappedArray`

So you can get the `WrappedArray` as array as

```
val data = collected.map(_.getList[(Double, Double)](1))
```

This will give you `Array[(Double, Double)]` now you can use as an array

To get only first element you need to do `data.map(_._1)`

Hope this helps!